# what is the best way to use a "soft delete" technique using HABTM

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

Currently I am working with cakephp framework. In my project there are three tables ( for example: menu, menu_position, and men_position_rel ).

In menu table i have id, menu_title column

In menu_position table i have id, position_title column

In men_position_rel table i have menu_id, position_id column

Using HABTM tables in CakePHP 2.x, what is the best way to use a "soft delete" technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got an easy & primary solution here: http://mrphp.com.au/blog/working-habtm-form-data-cakephp